# Add new mesh issue 3.4

Tags: mesh, origin

Has never happened before and prob easy solution, but when I add any new mesh, it is facing the camera, not xyz orientation, have been searching web for 3 hours, but nothing of relevance.

Answer (score 3):

We can hope it is an easy solution. Under Header > Edit > Preferences, the 'Editing' tab, you can find this setting:

[image]

Which sets the initial state of these, the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> operators, when called:

[image]

Comment: ta alot, easy peasy, dont remember going to that menu and changing things, maybe following tutorials and putting in the wrong shortcut in the finger dance, but anyway, should have come here first, willdo next time! cheers cresco